# Spring Boot, MongDB and Kotlin

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm trying to add a unique composite key in my document as follows:

```
@Document
@CompoundIndexes({
    CompoundIndex(def = "{'firstName':1, 'lastName':1}", name = "compound_index_1", unique = true)
})
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant.
```

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays are passed to annotations differently in Kotlin. Check out the [docs on kotlinlang](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html) and you'll see this snippet down near the bottom:

```
// Kotlin 1.2+:
@AnnWithArrayMethod(names = ["abc", "foo", "bar"]) 
class C

// Older Kotlin versions:
@AnnWithArrayMethod(names = arrayOf("abc", "foo", "bar")) 
class D
```

So your curly braces aren't going to work here, you'll need square brackets.

```
@Document
@CompoundIndexes(value = [
    CompoundIndex(def = "{'firstName':1, 'lastName':1}",
                  name = "compound_index_1", unique = true)
    ])
```